# Does mixing impl with generic parameters and without them have any implications?

Tags: generics, rust

Say, I have the following code:

```
use std::ptr::NonNull;
use std::marker::PhantomPinned;
use std::pin::Pin;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Unmovable {
    data: Vec<String>,
    cache: Option<NonNull<String>>,
    _pin: PhantomPinned,
}

impl<'a> Unmovable {
    pub fn new(data: Vec<String>) -> Pin<Box<Self>> {
        let internal = Self {
            data,
            cache: None,
            _pin: PhantomPinned
        };

        let mut boxed = Box::pin(internal);
        let cache = if boxed.data.len() > 0 {
            Some(NonNull::from(&boxed.data[0]))
        } else {
            None
        };

        unsafe {
            let ref_mut: Pin<&mut Unmovable> = Pin::as_mut(&mut boxed);
            Pin::get_unchecked_mut(ref_mut).cache = cache;
        }

        boxed
    }
    pub fn get_cache(&'a self) -> Option<&'a String> {
        Some(unsafe { self.cache?.as_ref() })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let unm = Unmovable::new(vec!["hello".to_owned(), "there".to_owned()]);
    println!("{:?}", unm);
    println!("{:?}", unm.get_cache());
}
```

I wonder, is there any difference at all whether the function `new` is implemented within a generic-specified `impl` block or separately without that generic parameter, given that it is not used there. To tell the truth, I'm somewhat surprised that Rust does allow this, impl a function which does not make use of all generics, since it is forbidden for structs, for instance. So I'm quite curious if there are some implications about such a mixed declaration.

Would the `new` function be tantamount to a separate implementation without generics next to `impl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be disallowed for type parameters or const generics. But free lifetimes on impl are allowed. They are only disallowed if used in an associated type. The rationale is explained [in the source code](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/f001f9301c889101d8a71358b64b96e9707c832b/compiler/rustc_typeck/src/impl_wf_check.rs#L176-L193):

````rust
    // (*) This is a horrible concession to reality. I think it'd be
    // better to just ban unconstrained lifetimes outright, but in
    // practice people do non-hygienic macros like:
    //
    // ```
    // macro_rules! __impl_slice_eq1 {
    //     ($Lhs: ty, $Rhs: ty, $Bound: ident) => {
    //         impl<'a, 'b, A: $Bound, B> PartialEq<$Rhs> for $Lhs where A: PartialEq<B> {
    //            ....
    //         }
    //     }
    // }
    // ```
    //
    // In a concession to backwards compatibility, we continue to
    // permit those, so long as the lifetimes aren't used in
    // associated types. I believe this is sound, because lifetimes
    // used elsewhere are not projected back out.
````

I don't know enough about rustc's internals to say for sure, but I'm pretty sure it will not affect anything. It is best to just not use that; use a lifetime on the methods that need it, not on the impl.