# Constrained lifetime parameter becomes unconstrained when used in associated type

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, lifetime

If I write the following code, it compiles fine.

```
impl<'a, T1, T2> Mul<TopOf<T1>> for LeftOf<T2>
where
    T1: Into<ObjRef<'a>>,
    T2: Into<ObjRef<'a>>,
{
    type Output = f32;

    fn mul(self, rhs: TopOf<T1>) -> Self::Output { todo!() }
}
```

However, if I write this (with the different `type Output`):

```
impl<'a, T1, T2> Mul<TopOf<T1>> for LeftOf<T2>
where
    T1: Into<ObjRef<'a>>,
    T2: Into<ObjRef<'a>>,
{
    type Output = Location<ObjRef<'a>>;

    fn mul(self, rhs: TopOf<T1>) -> Self::Output { todo!() }
}
```

then I get an error saying that `'a` is unconstrained. I can't understand how this makes sense, since the constraints are exactly the same, it is only the usage that is different. Is this a case of a poor error message (or even bug in the compiler) or is my thinking the one that is poor? What am I missing here?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72333315/2390010) applies to the cases where one is not using the lifetime and could write the code without it, but here I need the lifetime.

Comment: The answer I linked explains _why_. The answer to _how_ is "you can't, if you cannot change the trait or the struct to include a lifetime parameter or the associated type to be GAT".

Comment: In the linked answer you are implementing a struct with a lifetime parameter that isn't used in the `impl`. Here I'm implementing a trait with constraints that use the lifetime in `impl`. Everything works as long as I don't put the lifetime in Output. I can (and do) use `'a`, just not in Output. And I can use lifetimes in Output (https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b5cb3261a4e026405addd8bdfdbcc5d1). Or is my idea of (un)constrained lifetime wrong? `T1` depends on the lifetime, you can't figure out what the impl applies to if without knowing what `T1` is which requires you to know (use) `'a`.

Comment: The `where` clause is not considered a use. [The rules are here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/implementations.html#generic-implementations).

Comment: So, given the comment in the code you posted in your answer (`I think it'd be
 better to just ban unconstrained lifetimes outright`), in case that would go through (the banning) I wouldn't even be able to write the first version, right? (even though it is sound and determinate)

Comment: Yes. That is the idea.

Answer (score 0):

It's unconstrained because it shows up nowhere in the Trait definition. You can quickly fix that by actually constraining it:

```
trait A<'output> {
    type Output: 'output;
    fn a(self) -> Self::Output;
}
```

And now implement the trait like so:

```
impl<'output, 'b, T: 'b> A<'output> for B<T> {
    type Output = &'output str;

    fn a(self) -> Self::Output { todo!() }
}
```

And if your `Output` type is static, this'll work:

```
// note the anonymous lifetime parameter on `A`
impl<'b, T: 'b> A<'_> for B<T> {
    type Output = f32;

    fn a(self) -> Self::Output { todo!() }
}
```

Comment: Why is there no error on `struct B` then? It's as much (un)constrained as in `struct C`. Your solution also suggests that I can't implement what I wanted, since I can't exactly change the `Mul` trait, is that correct?